# Unions in Python

Tags: python

Say I'm given a tuple of strings, representing relationships between objects, for example:

```
connections = ("dr101-mr99", "mr99-out00", "dr101-out00", "scout1-scout2","scout3-scout1", "scout1-scout4", "scout4-sscout", "sscout-super")
```

each dash "-" shows a relationship between the two items in the string. Then I'm given two items:

```
first = "scout2"
second = "scout3"
```

How might I go about finding if first and second are interrelated, meaning I could find a path that connects them, not necessarily if they are just in a string group.

Comment: What do you mean by "interrelated" -- Do you mean that they appear together in one of the elements, or that you can find a path from one to the other.  e.g. scout3 -> scout1 -> scout4 -> sscout?  (i.e. you're representing edges on a [graph](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Graphs))

Comment: Are you only ever going to check one `first` and one `second` value, or might there be many checks you'll need to make? Does the order of the relation matter (that is, does `"dr101-mr99"` indicate a different relationship than `"mr99-dr101"`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try concatenating the strings and using the `in` operator to check if it is an element of the tuple `connections`:

```
if first + "-" + second in connections:
    # ...
```

**Edit:**

You can also use the `join()` function:

```
if "-".join((first, second)) in connections:
    # ...
```

Comment: But what about `'+'.join((second, first))` ;-)

Comment: I was editing it. It took me some time to check if the syntax was the correct :)

Comment: I wasn't actually talking about the `join` part.  I was actually thinking about the _order_ of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on doing this any number of times, I'd consider frozensets...

```
connections_set = set(frozenset(c.split('-')) for c in connections)
```

Now you can do something like:

```
if frozenset((first, second)) in connections_set:
   ...
```

and you have an O(1) solution (plus the O(N) upfront investment).  Note that I'm assuming the order of the pairs is irrelevant.  If it's relevant, just use a `tuple` instead of `frozenset` and you're good to go.

---

If you actually need to walk through a graph, an adjacency list implementation might be a little better.

```
from collections import defaultdict

adjacency_dict = defaultdict(list)
for c in connections:
    left, right = c.split('-')
    adjacency_dict[left].append(right)
    # if undirected:  adjacency_dict[right].append(left)

class DFS(object):
   def __init__(self, graph):
       self.graph = graph

   def is_connected(self, node1, node2):
       self._seen = set()
       self._walk_connections(node1)
       output = node2 in self._seen
       del self._seen
       return output

   def _walk_connections(self, node):
       if node in self._seen:
           return
       self._seen.add(node)
       for subnode in self.graph[node]:
           self._walk_connections(subnode)

print DFS(adjacency_dict).is_connected()
```

Note that this implementation is definitely suboptimal (I don't stop when I found the node I'm looking for for example) -- and I don't check for an *optimal* path from node1 to node2.  For that, you'd want something like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set of pairs (tuples):

```
connections = {("dr101", "mr99"), ("mr99", "out00"), ("dr101", "out00")} # ...

if ("scout2", "scout3") in connections:
    print "scout2-scout3 in connections"
```

This only works if the 2 elements are already in the right order, though, because `("scout3", "scout2") != ("scout2", "scout3")`, but maybe this is what you want.

If the order of the items in the connection is not significant, you can use a set of frozensets instead (see mgilson's answer). Then you can look up pairs of item regardless of which order they appear in, but the order of the original pairs in `connections` is lost.